# To calculate percentage value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have data as below..

```
count              ID
----------------------
10                 1
20                 2
30                 4
```

How can I achieve the third column which calculates the percentage in oracle.

```
count              ID   %
-------------------------------------
10                 1    10/(10+20+30)
20                 2    20/(10+20+30)
30                 4    30/(10+20+30)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [RATIO_TO_REPORT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions142.htm#SQLRF00691)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/2016)

**Query**:

```
with your_table(count_, id_) as (
  select 10,1 from dual union all
  select 20,2 from dual union all
  select 30,4 from dual
  )
select count_, id_,
ratio_to_report(count_) over () as percentage
from your_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/2016/0)**:

```
| COUNT_ | ID_ |          PERCENTAGE |
|--------|-----|---------------------|
|     10 |   1 | 0.16666666666666666 |
|     20 |   2 |  0.3333333333333333 |
|     30 |   4 |                 0.5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, count, ( count / ( SELECT SUM(count) FROM table) * 100 ) as per FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Comment: You can remove multiplication 100 if you just want value/sumofvalue

Answer (score 0):

Window functions provides the best solution to this type of problem. What you are attempting to achieve is two levels of aggregation in one query of the table.

```
select id
      ,count(*)
      ,sum(count(*)) over () as CountOfAll
      ,(1.0 * count(*)) / sum(count(*)) over () as Pct
from some_table
group by id
```

In cases where the denominator may result in a zero, you have to wrap the Pct calculation in a CASE statement to avoid division by zero errors:

```
select id
  ,count(*)
  ,sum(count(*)) over () as CountOfAll
  ,case when sum(count(*)) over () = 0 
      then 0 
      else (1.0 * count(*)) / sum(count(*)) over () 
   end as Pct
from some_table
group by id
```

Window functions open up a lot more possibilities for creating aggregate results within a single query, and are a worthy tool to add to your SQL tool belt!